# iTunes Connect bank account issue

Tags: app-store-connect, iphone-developer-program

This is my first time experience in uploading an app on App Store.

The problem that I encountered is that my app is free with iAd. Do I have to set up a bank account in iTunes Connect before uploading it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to. There is a specific iAd contract you need to sign, in iTunesConnect (Contracts, Taxes and Banking). See the image: [image]

Comment: Well i have a student account, is it possible to set up to it?

Comment: Hi, you should rephrase your question introducing that information, since it is not the most usual case. Quite probably you'll need another account, or upgrading your account, but I have not looked into that.